# Cannot upen libusb shared object

Tags: linux, usb, libraries

I'm trying to use `heimdall` to install a custom Android ROM. When I run it, I get this:

```
./heimdall: error while loading shared libraries: libusb-1.0.so.0:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But I have libusb installed. Why can't it find the file?

Comment: Have you tried `locate libusb-1.0.so.0`? Which OS are you running? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @JosephR. it comes up blank

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, you should install libusbx.

Comment: This answer fixed my problem I was having w/ `lsusb` on CentOS 7. Maybe lsusb should be dependent on libusbx...